# how to add a file to a MediaItem using SetStream?

Tags: c#, sitecore, memorystream, sitecore-media-library

I have the following situation:

- I have a file on the server ("file");
- I have an existing item in the Media Library to which this file must be attached ("item").

I tried using the following:

```cs
var stream = new MemoryStream(file);
var mediaItem = MediaManager.GetMedia(item);
var mediaStream = new MediaStream(stream, extension, item);

mediaItem.SetStream(mediaStream);
```

But the last operation ALWAYS fail throwing an exception saying `"Cannot access closed stream"`, even though the stream appears to be open before running the last command.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `MediaManager.Creator.AttachStreamToMediaItem` method:

```cs
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
MediaManager.Creator.AttachStreamToMediaItem(fileStream, "mediaItemPath", fileName, options)
```

Comment: This worked. How did you learned this? I was trying to do just that - executing the code that runs whenever I attach a file to a MediaItem, but couldn't find the needle in the haystack. Is there any documentation about this anywhere?

Comment: I've learned that long time ago - every media item adding/changing functionality is accessible via `MediaManager.Creator`. That's the first place I always look now.